# Defining a variable within a function in OCaml

Tags: function, variables, functional-programming, ocaml

I've got a function numofday that I'd like to apply to two variables in another function that will return the number of days between the two given days, the functions themselves don't really matter, I guess this is more of a syntactic question but google didn't produce much.

What I want to do is something like (and this is what I tried that obviously did not work)

```
let daysbetween day1 day2 =
 let x = numofday day1;
 let y = numofday day2;
 x-y;;
```

I've tried removing let, removing semicolons, and using := instead of = and I just can't seem to get it to work. There has to be a way to define variables within a function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for ocaml's let binding is `let name=bindng in expr`
Here is the fixed code for you

```
let daysbetween day1 day2 =
  let x = numofday day1 in 
  let y = numofday day2 in
  x-y;;
```

Your specific examples can even assign both values at once by binding a tuple:

```
let daysbetween day1 day2 =
  let (x,y) = (numofday day1, numofday day2) in
  x - y
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I was wondering about that, I've still been trying to research it as I waited for a reply.  Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I don't really like the tuple assignment in this situation. It's more confusing than anything. An other way of doing it is by using the "and" keyword : let daysbetween day1 day2 =
  let x = numofday day1
  and y = numofday day2 in
  x-y;; Which does NOT have the same semantics as the two first solutions, but works in this situation, and indicates that y is not dependent on x.

Answer (score 2):

To build on rgrinberg's answer:
Single semicolon in OCaml is very different than that in Java or C.

In your case, it seems that you interpret semicolon's functionality as the ending mark of a statement.
However, semicolon is used as a separator for expressions. And OCaml expects the value before a semicolon to be of type unit, (), which side-effect functions usually return.

The expression:

```
();();();.....();x;;
```

Has the value of x.

How to use it then?

```
let x = 1;;
let y = 
    print_string("assigning x to y\n");
    x;;
```

Comment: I disagree with this post. The semantics of the semicolon and of the "in" keyword are very close. His problem is that he was syntactically wrong : after a let it's an "in", not a semicolon. Putting a semicolon here makes totally sense, and is a good idea to try. I would be possible that "let x = v" is an expression that puts v into x, and returns unit, as much as "x := v" is in Ocaml.

Comment: @double_squeeze : after a let it's an "in", not a semicolon -> The semantics of the semicolon and of the "in" keyword are very close. What's the logic? Should I say in OCaml x = v and x == v have very similar syntax?

Comment: Yes, but that's not my point. My point is that it's a good idea to try semicolon after a "let", but unfortunately for him, ocaml has a special syntax to end a "let" expression, and it's the keyword "in". Semicolon is very much to separate statements in ocaml, as it does in C or java, except that in ocaml they are called expressions.